# How do I squash a master branch down to one commit?

Tags: git

I have a git repository that has a lot of commits on it. These have been remotely pushed but I want to squash merge the changes down to a single commit. Is there any simple way to do that?

I suppose I could create a temporary squashed branch and then push delete master and then create a new master but is there an easier way?